# SQLKata simple SELECT query returning 'invalid object name' for legitimate table?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlkata

Has anyone used the SqlKata library and had issues doing even a simple SELECT * FROM TABLE? I've tried both the standard GET (which produces a query that has the table in [], and the GetRaw which produces the query without the []).

Both queries return invalid object name for a clearly available table? My application records the following in logs:

```
[Error] SELECT * FROM InSiteStoreInfo
[Error] Invalid object name 'InSiteStoreInfo'.
```

The example code I'm using is below (I've tried the non-raw version of Get as well).

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> GetQueryKata(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        LogLevel environmentLogLevel = (LogLevel)Convert.ToInt32(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOG_LEVEL"));
        string jsonOutput = null;
        APIGatewayProxyResponse proxyResponse = new APIGatewayProxyResponse(); 

        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
                await RetrieveParameterStoreValue(ParameterStoreStrings.Database, true, context, environmentLogLevel)))
            {

                var db = new QueryFactory(connection, new SqlServerCompiler());

                // Log the compiled query to the console
                db.Logger = compiled => {
                   CreateCloudWatchLog(compiled.ToString(),context,LogLevel.Error,environmentLogLevel);
                };

                var results = db.Query().FromRaw("InSiteStoreInfo").Get();
                CreateCloudWatchLog(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented),context, LogLevel.Error,environmentLogLevel);
                jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented);
            }

            proxyResponse = await BuildResponse(jsonOutput, HttpStatusCode.OK, context, environmentLogLevel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CreateCloudWatchLog(ex.Message, context, LogLevel.Error, environmentLogLevel);
            proxyResponse = await BuildResponse(ex.Message, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, context, environmentLogLevel);
        }

        return proxyResponse; 
    }
```

Comment: It indicates wrong connection

Comment: @amd that is super unhelpful. What is 'it' within the question? And when you say 'wrong connection' - what does this mean? Wrong in what way?